# Creating a Wrapper for strncpy to Insert Terminating null

Tags: c, wrapper, strncpy

I have decided to make a wrapper for `strncpy` as my source code requires me to do a lot of string copies. And I want to ensure that the string is terminated if the source is equal or greater than the destination.

This code will be used in production, so I just want to see if there are any potential dangers using this wrapper.

I have never done wrappers before so I am trying to make it perfect.

Many thanks for any advice,

```
/* Null terminate a string after coping */
char* strncpy_wrapper(char *dest, const char* source, 
                      const size_t dest_size, const size_t source_size)
{
    strncpy(dest, source, dest_size);
    /* 
     * Compare the different length, if source is greater
     * or equal to the destination terminate with a null.
     */
    if(source_size >= dest_size)
    {
        dest[dest_size - 1] = '\0';
    }

    return dest;
}
```

==== Edited updated ====

```
/* Null terminate a string after coping */
char* strncpy_wrapper(char *dest, const char* source, 
                      const size_t dest_size)
{
    strncpy(dest, source, dest_size);
    /* 
     * If the destination is greater than zero terminate with a null.
     */
    if(dest_size > 0)
    {
        dest[dest_size - 1] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        dest[0] = '\0'; /* Return empty string if the destination is zero length */
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check *dest_size* before accessing the array or you'll get into trouble:

```
if (dest_size > 0) {
    dest[dest_size - 1] = '\0';
}
```

---

Actually, now that I think of it, it's probably better to just die:

```
if (dest_size == 0) {
    fputs(stderr, "strncpy(x,y,0)");
    exit(1);
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have the same problem as with the original *strncpy()*, that *dest* may not be terminated if *dest_size* is 0.

Comment: I have just edited my question with updated source code. I have put an if else. If the dest is greater than 0. Always terminate the last element. Else insert a null in the first [0] element and return an empty destination string. What does that sound like?

Comment: You can't store a '\0' in *dest* if *dest* has zero size. You're not allowed to, since you may only access zero chars, but storing a '\0' means that you are accessing one char. I don't think it's a problem to die, it's like division through zero errors. It simply doesn't make any sense to call your function with *dest_size == 0*. It's a good idea to *fail early*, then you know at least where you messed up (in the call to strncpy()). Imagine the division operation failing silently, and giving you some random garbage as a result; very hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to check that source is greater than destination just always make the last char in the dest a '\0'.

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate the semi-standard BSD functions `strlcpy()` and `strlcat()`.

You should consider whether the ISO TR24731 functions such as `strncpy_s()` are appropriate and available where you need them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any constraints on the allocation of the buffer, `strndup` could be more appropriate.

It will allocate and copy at most `len` chars, and always terminate with NULL.

Answer (score 1):

if dest_size is the number of characters to be copied and source_size is the number of characters in source string.
you should try this:

```
 size_t numchars = dest_size > source_size ? source_size : dest_size;
 strncpy(dest,source,numchars) ;
 dest[numchars] = 0 ;
```

Comment: *strncpy()* will **not** 0-terminate *dest* by itself. The 0-character will always come from *source*. That means your example will not work as the OP intends.